# Reciprocal of a Binomial

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm wondering if there is any formula to do this.

Suppose $B$~$B(N,p)$, and hence we have $E[B]=Np,D[B]=Np(1-p)$. I'm just wondering how to do $E[\frac{1}{c+B}]$,for some $c>0$?

Thanks.

Comment: No general formula except in terms of incomplete beta functions (thus, more an equivalent formulation of the problem than a solution). The case c=1 is easy.

Comment: @Did Isn't it easy for any positive integer $c$, considering it is equal to the case $B(N+c-1,p)$ conditioned on first $c-1$ experiments being successful?

Comment: Following up on @cangrejo 's comment, perhaps this could be modeled as a Poisson Binomial Distribution with the first $c$ Bernoulli experiments having probabilities $p_1=\ldots=p_c=1$ and $p_{c+1}=\ldots=p_{N}=p$. The expected value of such r.v. is $c + Np$, but this is not the expected value of the reciprocal of this r.v., which is what is being asked.

Answer (score 7):

Law of the unconscious statistician:

$$
\mathbb E[g(X)] = \sum_xg(x)\mathbb P(X=x)
$$

In this case, we have the sum:

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[\frac1{c+B}\right]&=\sum_{n=0}^N\frac1{c+n}\mathbb P(B=n)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^N\begin{pmatrix}N\\n\end{pmatrix}\frac{p^n(1-p)^{N-n}}{c+n}
\end{align}

[According to Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bn=0%7D%5EN%20Binomial%5BN,n%5D%28p%5En%281-p%29%5E%7BN-n%7D%29/%28c%2bn%29), this is equal to:

$$
\frac{(1-p)^N\,_2F_1\left(c, -N; c+1; \frac{p}{p-1}\right)}c
$$

where $\,_2F_1$ is the [Hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).  Since pretty much any function you've ever heard of is a special case of the hypergeometric function, this isn't a particularly interesting result, and I doubt there's any nice way to find it.

Comment: Upvoted for the "Law of the unconscious statistician".

Answer (score 4):

A closed-form expression and the answer to this question is given in the paper by Chao, M. T., and W. E. Strawderman. “[Negative Moments of Positive Random Variables](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2284399).” Journal of the American Statistical Association, vol. 67, no. 338, 1972, pp. 429–431. JSTOR, www.jstor.org/stable/2284399.

Answer (score 1):

For large $n$ (switching form $N$ to $n$), the following bounds might be useful.

Let us assume $p \in (0, 1/2]$. Then, for $B \sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$ and $\delta \in (0,p)$, we have
$$
\mathbb P( B \le \delta n) \le e^{-n D(\delta||p)}
$$
where $D(\delta||p)$ is the KL divergence between probability vectors $(\delta, 1-\delta)$ and $(p,1-p)$.

It follows that for all $n \ge 1$ and $0 < \delta < p \le 1/2$,
$$
\frac1{c+np} \;\le\; \mathbb E \Bigl[ \frac1{c+ B}\Bigr] \;\le \;
\frac{1}{c + n \delta} (1-e^{-n D(\delta||p)}) + \frac1{c} e^{-n  D(\delta||p)}
$$
where the lower bound is by the Jensen's inequality and the upper bound is by conditioning on the event $\{B > \delta n\}$ and its complement and bounding $1/(c+B)$ on the two events by $1/(c+n\delta)$ and $1/c$, respectively.

---

Another useful upper bound:
$$
\frac1{1+np} \;\le\; \mathbb E \Bigl[ \frac1{1+ B}\Bigr] \;\le \;
\frac{1}{(1+n)p}.
$$