# Equation with expected value of inverse of a binomial variable

Tags: probability

I need to solve an equation $\Bbb E\frac{1}{a + X} = b$ where $X\sim \mathrm{Bin}(p; n)$ in terms of $p$, where $a,b> 0$ and integer $n$ are given. As far as I understood from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497976/reciprocal-of-a-binomial), the LHS does not admit a particularly elegant closed form, so no big luck inverting it. On the other hand, I rather know an approximate value of $p$ for $n$ large enough. Perhaps, in that case it may make sense to assume that $X$ is almost normal: I have not found any results on how hard is to compute the LHS in that case. Any ideas?

Comment: When $n$ increase the LHS will converge to $0$ except for $p=0$

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the LHS closed-form from the answer in the your link, you can in that closed form substitute $Q=(1-p)^n \, _2F_1\left(a,-n;a+1;p/(p-1)\right)$ by some approximation. To make one note that

$$Q^{(m)}(0)=\frac{(m!)^2 \binom{n}{m}}{\underset{i=0}{\overset{m}{\prod }}(a+i)}\quad,\quad Q^{(m)}(1)=\frac{(m!)^2 \binom{n}{m}}{\underset{i=n-m}{\overset{n}{\prod}}(a+i)}$$

It doesn't make sense to consider just $n$ large, because the LHS converge to 0 pointwise except for $p=0$. (I suppose you want $0\leq p\leq1$)

Comment: I meant the asymptotics of $p$ as $n$ goes to infinity

Answer (score 0):

When $p$ is constant, we have that $E\left[\frac{1}{1+X}\right]=O\left(\frac{1}{n\cdot p}\right)$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$ as shown by [Cribari-Neto et al. (2000)](http://bibliotecadigital.fgv.br/ojs/index.php/bre/article/viewFile/2760/1694). See also the paper by Chao, M. T., and W. E. Strawderman. “[Negative Moments of Positive Random Variables](http://bibliotecadigital.fgv.br/ojs/index.php/bre/article/viewFile/2760/1694).” Journal of the American Statistical Association, vol. 67, no. 338, 1972, pp. 429–431. JSTOR, www.jstor.org/stable/2284399.