# Expectation of the inverse of Binomial distribution

Tags: binomial-distribution

Suppose the random variable $X_i$ are i.i.d and follow $Binomial(N,p)$.

Then, can we compute the following expectation?

$E\big[\frac{1}{a+X}\big]$ where $a>0$.

Comment: It can be written in terms of the ordinary [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), if that's any help.

Comment: possible duplicate, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497976/reciprocal-of-a-binomial

Comment: @dnqxt Thanks! Do I have to remove the question?

Comment: Welcome. I don't know about removing the question -- perhaps someone else would answer.